# Who owns a PDA that anchor inits?

Tags: anchor, pda

When doing init with anchor, is the pda owned by the program that creates it or by the system program?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `init` constraint it will assign ownership to the program calling the function unless you ask it to assign a different owner using the `owner` constraint. e.g.

```
    #[account(
        init, payer = payer, space = 8 + 8,
        owner = other_program.key(),
        seeds = [b"other_seed"], bump
    )]
    pub pda_for_other_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

You don't need to init a PDA that you want to be owned by the system program because all accounts are owned by the system program by default.